# Authentication between client-server and web applications

Tags: security, session, authentication, web-applications, client-server

I have two applications, one is a desktop client and the other is a web application which is optionally embedded into the desktop client. Both talk to separate servers with separate databases and separate user authentication mechanisms. The servers may communicate with each other.

I need to be able to log in to the desktop application and use the embedded web application without having to enter the web client's username/password.

The web app is developed at our side so major changes are possible (within reason). Architecture is .NET on Windows (IIS and SQL Server).
The desktop app is developed elsewhere so changes should be minimal; making http-requests and passing a token around is ok but creating a new authentication mechanism isn't. Architecture unknown, solution should be platform independent.

Can I use some sort of trust between the two servers to create a one time authentication token which the desktop client can pass to the web client to create a session?

Are there any existing implementations of this or another similar use case I could slot in? Note that internet connectivity must not be required, only access to the two servers is guaranteed.

If there aren't any easy/quick/free solutions, I was thinking something like this (D is desktop application, W is web application):

1. User logs in to Client D and wants to open Client W
2. Server D asks Server W for a token for a specific user
3. Server W creates a new token, maps it internally to the requested username and returns the token
4. Client D logs in to Client W using username and token
5. Server W creates a new session and forgets the token so it cannot be used again

Traffic between servers would be over SSL/TLS, IP whitelisted, authenticated using a preconfigured passcode and includes a unique counter and timestamp to prevent replay attacks.
The desktop client would communicate to the web application by making a request to the server via the embedded browser. For authentication it would HTTPS POST the username and token to a login page.
Communication between clients and their representative servers is assumed to be secure.

Is there something I'm still missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution that is the least obtrusive will be best. I like the idea of modularized authentication that you can drop in new authentication methods easily. You simply have two active authentication modules.

Let's take a look at server D:

1. User Name/Password authentication. You take user name and password and validate it (or hopefully its hash) against what's in the database and return a token. Requests with the returned token will be successful until the token expires.
2. Peer authentication. You take the given session token from the request and submit it to Server W for validation. If Server W doesn't return 200 you should forbid access. This would also be a good opportunity to share session data.

It seems like you're already thinking down this path, but I would recommend that you don't have the servers ask each other for tokens. Instead have the servers ask each other for session data using the token that is valid for that server. If you log in with user/pass on Server D, have Server D give you a session token that is valid with Server D. Then when communicating with Server W, have Server W ask Server D if the given session token is valid. Server D can simply return yes/no or return all the public session data for the given token.

This solution has at least two benefits over the one you propose:

1. You don't have to keep two tokens. You just store whichever token the last server you authenticated with user/pass gave you. This also enables you to deal with servers as if they used the same authentication which allows you more flexability in the future if you wish to change the auth method.
2. Token expiration is more straightforward. You won't have mismatching expiration to deal with. Whenever your single token has expired you are no longer authenticated with either server.

What do you think? Make sense?

Btw, I think SSL protects against replay attacks.

Comment: Nice, that's much cleaner! Also, thanks for the heads up about SSL and replay attacks :)